# Bind input select to group of checkboxes jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm very new in jquery and I need a little bit help.
I have a selectbox with 3 groups. 
group1 with value 1,3,5
group2 with value 1,2,3,4,5
group3 with value 1,5

When I select a group, the checkboxes are to be marked.
When I select group1, check checkbox 1,3,5
when I select group3, check checkbox 1,5

```
HTML:
<div>
 <select name="group_id" id="input-group" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1,3,5">Group 1</option>
  <option value="1,2,3,4,5">Group 2</option>
  <option value="1,5">Group 3</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1" />
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="2"/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="3"/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value="4"/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" value="5"/>
</div>

JS:
$('select').on('change', function() {

})
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/rd2mz7nh/1/

I hope you can help me and thanks for the support

BR Thomas

Comment: Check out my updated version of your fiddle, let me know what you think: https://jsfiddle.net/q6th3zds/

Comment: I'll provide an explaination of what I did if that is what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to compare the selected option values with each check box and set to checked accordingly. Below is the code

```
$("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false); // Uncheck all when page is loaded

    $('#input-group').on('change', function() {
      var selectedValues = this.value;
      $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        var isChecked = selectedValues.split(',').indexOf($(this).attr("value")) > -1;
        $(this).prop("checked", isChecked);
      });
    });
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/4pqg1w8c/

Comment: Hello, thanks, thanks thanks - this is what I need. Thanks for both solution, but I think this is easier.

Comment: Please up-vote and set this as answer. It will be useful to others